# python crash course heroku ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am currently following along python crash course to deploy my learning log project to heroku, having errors. Would appreciate any help as I am new to this. Running 'heroku open' in cmd gives me the application error page, which I have tried to fix but running  'heroku run python manage.py migrate' gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'
```

in settings.py at the very bottom I have added

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

and at the top

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
#My apps
    'learning_logs',
    'users',
    
    #Thirsd party apps.
    'bootstrap4', 
    
    #Default django apps.
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

my pipfile(which I have locked while trying to follow other solutions)

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
asgiref = "==3.3.1"
beautifulsoup4 = "==4.9.3"
bootstrap4 = "==0.1.0"
dj-database-url = "==0.5.0"
django-bootstrap4 = "==2.3.1"
django-heroku = "==0.3.1"
gunicorn = "==20.0.4"
psycopg2 = "==2.8.6"
pytz = "==2020.5"
soupsieve = "==2.1"
sqlparse = "==0.4.1"
whitenoise = "==5.2.0"
Django = "==3.1.4"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.3.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bootstrap4==0.1.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.4
django-bootstrap4==2.3.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
pytz==2020.5
soupsieve==2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

Thank you for trying to make sense of this for me! Thank you everyone!

Comment: Why do you have a pipfile and a requirements.txt file? Usually you use one or the other. I'm the author of PCC, so I'll steer you toward the approach used in the book. Delete the pipfile and keep the requirements.txt file. It looks like the core issue is that you installed the packages bootstrap4 and django-bootstrap4 in your local environment. Delete the reference to bootstrap4 in your requirements.txt file, but keep the reference to django-bootstrap4. Then commit your project again, and try pushing again. I would guess that something in bootstrap4 is conflicting with django-bootstrap4.

Comment: Hi sir! Thank you so much for the help, it works now! Not sure why it didnt at the start, but thank you so much for the help (And the really good book!) Been seeing your comments helping on reddit as well. Cheers man! :)

Answer (score 0):

See japhyr's comment ^^^

"Why do you have a pipfile and a requirements.txt file? Usually you use one or the other. I'm the author of PCC, so I'll steer you toward the approach used in the book. Delete the pipfile and keep the requirements.txt file. It looks like the core issue is that you installed the packages bootstrap4 and django-bootstrap4 in your local environment. Delete the reference to bootstrap4 in your requirements.txt file, but keep the reference to django-bootstrap4. Then commit your project again, and try pushing again. I would guess that something in bootstrap4 is conflicting with django-bootstrap4."